# No overload for 'ItemDataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net, itemdatabound

I have a nested repeater
Because of that no control in my code is visible and because of that I found out that I had to use FindControl to get the controls visible.
I want to pass on a value from a lable after a buttonclick but I'm having a hard time getting it right

The label with the value

```
<asp:Label ID="lblordernr" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.sid").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
```

The button I use:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPaid" runat="server" Text="Paid" OnClick="rlrtAdres_ItemDataBound"
                        Style="height: 26px" CssClass="knop" CommandName="btnPaid" />
```

RepeaterItemDataBound

```
protected void rlrtAdres_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblordernr = e.Item.FindControl("lblordernr") as Label;
    Repeater myRepeater = (Repeater)sender;
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "btnPaid":
            MutateSold("paid", lblordernr.Text);
            break;
    }
}
```

I first had a normal buttonOclick control but I just dont know how to combine it with the label value and call the final method "MutateSold" for database purposes with a nested repeater and every invisible control in this repeater

```
protected void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control myControllblordernr = FindControl("lblordernr");
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "btnPaid":
            MutateSold("paid", myControllblordernr.ToString());
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error you posted in the title because the `Click` event of `btnPaid` expects an event handler with a signature like:

`protected void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

You're pointing it at a method that has a signature of:

`protected void rlrtAdres_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)`

If `btnPaid` and `lblordernr` are in the same `ItemTemplate` for the repeater, you can call `FindControl` on the button to get a reference to `lblordernr`. For example, if `btnPaid` is declared like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPaid" runat="server" Text="Paid" OnClick="btnPaid_Click"
    Style="height: 26px" CssClass="knop"  />
```

the following code will get you a reference to `lblOrderNr`.

```
protected void btnPaid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btnPaid = (Button)sender;
    var lblOrderNr = (Label)btnPaid.FindControl("lblordernr");
    var labelText = lblOrderNr.Text;

    //Do whatever else needs to be done
}
```

Alternatively, you can just add the value in `lblOrderNr` to the `CommandArgument` property on the button and get it right from there as well.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPaid" runat="server" Text="Paid" OnClick="btnPaid_Click"
    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.sid").ToString()%>'
    Style="height: 26px" CssClass="knop" />


protected void btnPaid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btnPaid = (Button)sender;
    var labelText = btnPaid.CommandArgument;

    //Do whatever else needs to be done
}
```

Comment: @Sjemmie No problem, see the update to my answer. Hope that helps.